# How do I enforce HTTPS on both my root domain and WWW subdomain on GitHub Pages?

Tags: github, https, github-pages

I have set up my GitHub Pages project site to enforce HTTPS, and it works fine when I browse to http://rootdomain.com, http://www.rootdomain.com, or https://rootdomain.com — they all correctly display https://rootdomain.com.

However, when I browse to https://www.rootdomain.com, I get a browser privacy error `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`. Is there  way to make this URL redirect to https://rootdomain.com as well?

I have configured my DNS (Google Domains DNS) as follows:

[image: DNS Configuration]

My CNAME file contains `rootdomain.com`, and my GitHub Pages Custom Domain is set up as follows:

[image: GitHub Pages Custom Domain Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, my DNS provider (Google Domains) has a feature to enable SSL for Subdomain Forwarding. So I removed the CNAME for my WWW subdomain and created a Subdomain Forward Synthetic Record as follows:

[image]

Google will create an SSL cert for the subdomain, which they say can take up to 24 hours. When I did it, it only took a couple of hours. Now https://www.rootdomain forwards to https://rootdomain as expected.